# Check in buildForm method of custom form class if the form was submitted

Tags: forms

I have created a large form with a class extending `FormBase`. Many of the elements rendered within the form are only necessary for the user to see - there are not so many really relevant fields in the form but all this data gathering and rendering takes time.

When a form is submitted the `buildForm()` method is called first and after that the `submitForm()` method. Then the buildForm() method gets called again which then is really used to render the form for the user.

I now wonder if it is possible to check within the `buildForm()` method if it is called during the first run before `submitForm()` or if it is used during the second run to actually render it.

`FormState->isSubmitted()` does not do the trick - this is false on buildForm() on the first run.

Comment: Check $form_state->getUserInput(). See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/288795/how-to-determine-if-loading-a-form-or-submitting-a-form-in-hook-form-alter

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is submitted when there is user input:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  if ($form_state->getUserInput()) {
    // The form was submitted. 
    // Build a minimal $form containing only the necessary form elements
    // to submit the user input.
  }
}
```

BTW, buildForm() can be called again, in the same request, if a submit handler causes a form rebuild or in Ajax forms. The user input is processed, $form_state->getValues() and $form_state->getTriggeringElement() are filled with data and can then be used to build a different version of the form.

If the form is not rebuilding it redirects by default to the same URL and builds a new empty form. If this takes too long and the user probably doesn't want to submit the form again, you can change this default behavior and set a different URL.

For example, redirect to the homepage and set a message:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $this->messenger()->addStatus($this->t('The form has been submitted.'));
  $form_state->setRedirect('<front>');
}
```